# When will this patent be availabe for clinical application by healthcare professionals?

Tags: licensing, application, copyright

> I am a healthcare professional (RMT) in Ontario with many patients who come to me concerned with their cellulite. I also educate the public about cellulite and provide treatments geared specifically treating cellulite and also provide detailed personalized home-care instructions. In practice my daily work involves manipulating and augmenting the fascia/connective tissue/E CM Extra Cellular Matrix, scar tissue, muscle and joints. I do so to assist patients to heal better and faster from minor to severe muscoloskeletal injuries such as RSI repetitive strains injuries and MVA motor vehicle accident injuries.
>   I also include movement therapies and exercises to reset kinetic movement patterns and posture alignments.>
>
> I see, palpate and understand how cellulite accumulates and adheres in the tissues. I understand my patients concerns and want to help them much more.>
>
> In practice my clinical results (approx.3x wk./2-3 wk) present a small percentage in terms of overall desired results for treating cellulite compared to a 95% percent track record for patients (compliant) with injuries.
>
> I understand how DMSO works in the process of cellulite elimination. The body renders the toxic adipocytes to apoptosis after being exposed to DMSO. Macrophages eat up toxic dead fat cells.

When will this patent be available for clinical use and application by healthcare professionals?

Comment: Hi, Ask Patents is a website to ask about the patent process or to help find Prior Art on US Patent Applications and US Patents. Unfortunately, questions about the production of products covered by these patents is outside the scope of this site.